# Index Match Match - First row correct, then all subsequent rows duplicate this data

Tags: excel, indexing, match

So, I am trying to use Index Match Match to pull back some information, but the issue I am hitting is, the first row is correct, but all rows below, return the same data.

But I cannot resolve this, any ideas?

The formula I am using is:

`=INDEX(Data[[Total Net ]],MATCH([Contractor]&[Charge Rate],Data[Contractor]&Data[Charge Rate],0))`

The data table I am pulling from is:

[image: Wasn't sure how else to show you so link here]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `MATCH([Contractor]&[Charge Rate],Data[Contractor]&Data[Charge Rate],0)` returns what?  I think probably "1".

Comment: Yes the match brings back "1", ah so that would be the issue...

Comment: You may need to look at `SUMPRODUCT` function or an array [CSE] formula.